# Convert table with cells lat/long four corners data to raster

Tags: r, converters, gis, raster

I have a data set in the following format.each row represents the coordinates of the four corners of a cell and the last column is the value associated to the cell.

```
structure(list(lon1 = c(-44.48, -42.53, -40.56, -38.56, -36.55
), lat1 = c(49.88, 50.14, 50.35, 50.52, 50.64), lon2 = c(-44.69, 
-42.71, -40.71, -38.68, -36.64), lat2 = c(50.51, 50.77, 50.98, 
51.16, 51.28), lon3 = c(-43.71, -41.71, -39.7, -37.66, -35.61
), lat3 = c(50.64, 50.88, 51.08, 51.23, 51.33), lon4 = c(-43.5, 
-41.54, -39.56, -37.56, -35.54), lat4 = c(50.02, 50.25, 50.44, 
50.59, 50.69), TotHg = c(8.5, 9.02, 9.21, 8.75, 8.53)), .Names = c("lon1", 
"lat1", "lon2", "lat2", "lon3", "lat3", "lon4", "lat4", "TotHg"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I would like to convert it to a raster to be used in GIS. At the moment I do not know the coordinate system but I am investigating. All I know is that the resolution is supposed to be 2.5°. How can this be done in either R or in ArcMap? I have read a similar thread but I am not sure if it is the same situation since I have the coordinates for the four corners of each cell.this is the other question How can I convert data in the form of lat, lon, value into a raster file using R?

Comment: Please reformat the dataset, it is not readable right now.

Comment: Is this better? I tried but not sure how to do. I copy and pasted from Excel.

Comment: It is best to format it as code, and align the columns. Easiest is to just read it into R (`read.table`), print it, and paste the result as code. Even better is to make the data easily pastable for us using e.g. `dput`.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I execute your comment :)

Comment: `rasterImage` takes as arguments the coordinates of the 4 corners.  However, your question about **resolution** is not one of graphing but rather of the resolution of the underlying data. Any raster-like algorithm will plot a pixel for every data point you have, no more and no less.  So, were you assigned to interpolate your data on a 2.5-degree grid?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I was given the data table and told the resolution of the grid is 2.5 degrees, I don't have to interpolate but just create a raster where each totHg value is associated to a raster cell. How do I deal with the fact that I have 4 data points per row?